# boost::asio::read() blocks forever

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to learn how Boost.asio works. I've written a basic server and client example as such:

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#define PORT 27015

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;

std::string read(tcp::socket& socket) {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::read(socket, buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "read error: " << error.message() << "\n";
        return "ERROR";
    }
    else {
        std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data());
        return data;
    }
}

void send(tcp::socket& socket, const std::string& message) {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), error);
    if (error)
        std::cerr << "send error: " << error.message() << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "sent \"" << message << "\" to the client" << "\n";
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), PORT)); // create listener for new connection(s)
    tcp::socket socket(io_service); // socket creation

    std::cout << "awaiting connection..." << "\n";
    acceptor.accept(socket); // direct connection(s) to the socket we created
    std::cout << "accepted connection!" << "\n";

    std::string received = read(socket); // receive data
    std::cout << "received message: " << received << "\n";

    send(socket, "hello from server!"); // send data
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#define PORT 27015

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service); // socket creation

    std::string server_ipv4_address = "192.168.1.2";
    std::cout << "connecting to server at " << server_ipv4_address << "\n";

    try {
        socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(server_ipv4_address), PORT)); // connection
        std::cout << "connected!" << "\n";
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "error while connecting: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    boost::system::error_code error; // error holder

    std::string message = "hello from client!!\n";
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), error); // send message to server
    if (error)
        std::cerr << "send failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "sent \"" << message << "\" to the server" << "\n";

    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
    boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error); // receive from server
    if (error && error != boost::asio::error::eof)
        std::cerr << "receive failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
    else {
        std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(receive_buffer.data());
        std::cout << "received data: " << data << "\n";
    }
}
```

The connection gets established properly, but the read() function from the server blocks the program as either it does not receive data from the client, or there is a problem with the way I'm calling it. What seems to be the issue with the `boost::asio::read()` here?
Everything works properly if I swap `boost::asio::read` with `boost::asio::read_until` as shown below. Why does the function work properly in the client but not in the server?

```
std::string read(tcp::socket& socket) {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buffer, "\n");
    std::string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data());
    return data;
}
```

Comment: That is the nature of IO read operations, you block until you receive the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read with the completion condition `transfer_all` means it will just keep reading until the buffer is full or the connection becomes invalid.

The buffer will "never" be full (since it's a DynamicBuffer).

So that leaves the cause that the client never hangs up.

> Everything works properly if I swap boost::asio::read with boost::asio::read_until as shown below.

Exactly. Because then you have another reason to stop reading. Mind you, it could still block forever (when a `'\n'` never arrives).

> Why does the function work properly in the client but not in the server?

It doesn't. It appears to because the server, apparently, does shutdown the connection (signalling EOF). [You would notice this because a subsequent read would return error_code boost::asio::error::eof.]

Comment: Thank you this is just what I was looking for.